# How to iterate through an array of objects and add up the properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, function, loops

Below is a sample array of objects :

```
[{Name : Deji, Age: 12}, {Name : Sonia, Age 13}, {Name : Fabio, Age: 21}]
```

How do I iterate through the arrays in such a way as to add up the ages of the people in the array.

Is there a function that can add up the ages of the player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your JSON is not a valid one, it should be,

> [   {
>       "Name": "Deji",
>       "Age": 12   },   {
>       "Name": "Sonia",
>       "Age": 13   },   {
>       "Name": "Fabio",
>       "Age": 21   } ]

With angularjs you can juse use  **[`array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)** function to calculate the total.

**`DEMO`**

```js
 angular.module('MyModule', [])
.controller( 'MyController', function($scope){
 $scope.data = [
  {
    "Name": "Deji",
    "Age": 12
  },
  {
    "Name": "Sonia",
    "Age": 13
  },
  {
    "Name": "Fabio",
    "Age": 21
  }
];    
$scope.sum = function(items, prop){
        return items.reduce( function(a, b){
            return a + b[prop];
        }, 0);
};
$scope.totalAges = $scope.sum($scope.data, 'Age');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='MyModule' ng-controller='MyController'>
    <p>totalAges = {{totalAges}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: array.reduce  isn't limited to Angular but is a Javascript functional "Function".

Answer (score 3):

Use [**Array#forEach**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [**Array#reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=a) to iterate over array items and add the age of each player to your variable.

**forEach**

```js
const players = [{Name : 'Deji', Age: 12}, {Name : 'Sonia', Age: 13}, {Name : 'Fabio', Age: 21}];

let age = 0;

players.forEach(player => age += player.Age);

console.log(age);
```

**reduce**

```js
const players = [{Name : 'Deji', Age: 12}, {Name : 'Sonia', Age: 13}, {Name : 'Fabio', Age: 21}];

const age = players.reduce((sum, player) => sum + player.Age, 0);

console.log(age);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var players = [{Name : 'Deji', Age: 12}, {Name : 'Sonia', Age : 13}, {Name : 'Fabio', Age: 21}];
var age = 0;
players.forEach(function(el){
 age+=el.Age;
})
console.log(age)
```

Loop through each object using [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) , get the element and access Age property, and add it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var a = [{Name : 'Deji', Age: 12}, {Name : 'Sonia', Age : 13}, {Name : 'Fabio', Age: 21}];

var sum = 0;
for(var i of a){

sum += i.Age;

}

console.log(sum);
```